# Insert new row (rowspan) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, row, html-table

I have Javascript like the following:

```
function addRow(table1) {

            var table = document.getElementById(table1);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And HTML like the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Insert row" onclick="addRow('table1')" />
<table id="table1" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2><input type="text" name="txt1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a row with `rowspan=2`, and two rows with no rowspan. How do I write the following line so that once the user clicks the Insert Row button, three textboxes will be added into the new row?

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells.innerHTML;
```

Comment: @JosephSilber Seeing as this member is new, I think it was a matter of how the code was pasted into the question - it can get garbled sometimes. Therefore I don't see the need in such a smart remark especially when he's just trying to get help.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst - The OP has 2 answers and 5 questions under his belt. It's time to graduate.

Comment: Being a smart ass doesn't contribute to a productive community regardless of the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your code you have:

```
> newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells.innerHTML;
```

I think you mean:

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

But anyway, have you considered using a cloned row instead? e.g. something like the following (untested):

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var row = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var i = inputs.length;

  while (i--) {

    if (inputs[i].type = 'text') {
      inputs[i].vaule = '';

      // Might want to change other properties too
    }
  }
  table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, never thought about `cloneNode()` before. But it will only clone the first row..

Comment: @LorekBryanson—you can clone any node you want (and its descendants), I just used the first row because that's what you put in the OP.